# What are the requirements to teach at a software engineering "bootcamp?"

Tags: united-states, software

Suppose I had the expertise and industry experience to capably teach at a development bootcamp.

Am I required to obtain any teaching certificate of sorts before lecturing? Are the requirements different for teaching assistants?

I'm perusing the requirements for instructor roles in my area, and there seems to be no mention of a relevant requirement. Since these are unaccredited programs, are such requirements waived?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what this bootcamp is, how it is organized, and who it will serve?  The only situation I know where a certification might be required is if this is part of the educational program of a public or private K-12 school.  Also, this would likely be governed by state law, not federal, so please add a state tag.

Answer (score 2):

The specific details are determined at the state level, however the certification requirement is related to "accreditation" and applies to K-12 schools (universities and vocational schools are accreditable, but most instructors do not have state teaching certificates). Drawing on Washington state law, the [state board of education](http://www.sbe.wa.gov/faq/accreditation.php#two) informs us that "Accreditation is a voluntary process for granting public recognition to institutions that meet external standards of quality". The SBE is granted some powers regarding accreditation: per [RCW 28A.305.130(5)](http://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=28A.305.130), "the state board of education shall"

> Accredit, subject to such accreditation standards and procedures as
>   may be established by the state board of education, all private
>   schools that apply for accreditation, and approve, subject to the
>   provisions of RCW 28A.195.010, private schools carrying out a program
>   for any or all of the grades kindergarten through twelve. However, no
>   private school may be approved that operates a kindergarten program
>   only and no private school shall be placed upon the list of accredited
>   schools so long as secret societies are knowingly allowed to exist
>   among its students by school officials

The board's certification requirement enjoys some exceptions, under [RCW 28A.195.010](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=28A.195.010):

> private schools should be subject only to those minimum state controls
>   necessary to insure the health and safety of all the students in the
>   state and to insure a sufficient basic education to meet usual
>   graduation requirements
>
> In exceptional cases, people of unusual competence but without
>   certification may teach students so long as a certified person
>   exercises general supervision

Teaching certificates enter the picture due to [RCW 28A.410.025](http://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=28a.410&full=true):

> No person shall be accounted as a qualified teacher within the meaning
>   of the school law who is not the holder of a valid teacher's
>   certificate or permit issued by lawful authority of this state.

It's not that the requirements are waived, rather there simply *are* no certification requirements on programming bootcamp.